# Need help adding filters to a MySQL search query

Tags: mysql

Okay, lets say I have 3 tables...

One is called `media`, each row has a primary index of `media_id`.

One is called `keywords`, each row has a primary index of `keyword_id`.

And finally, I have another table called `keylinks`. There is no primary index, but there is a unique index of `media_id + keyword_id`. You can probably guess that this table is an index of keywords linked to media. The idea is that keywords can be linked to multiple pieces of media so that users can browse media based on the keywords they are linked to.

Right now, I am doing the following to fetch media linked to the keyword_id of `6`:

```
SELECT media.*, keywords.*
FROM media
    LEFT JOIN keylinks ON (keylinks.media_id = media.media_id)
    LEFT JOIN keywords ON (keywords.keyword_id = keylinks.keyword_id)
WHERE keywords.keyword_id = '6'
```

This works great, if I only want to return results linked by `6`. However, what if I wanted to find media that are linked not only to the keyword_id of `6` but also to a second (or third, etc) `keyword_id`.

My question is how would I retrieve a list of media that has a keylink to both `6` and possibly `8`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "keylink to both 6 and possibly 8"? You mean "keylink to both 6 and 8", right?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean... Get a list of media linked to both `6` AND `8`... with the ability to add more. So if I wanted I could do `6` AND `8` AND `12` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM media
WHERE media_id IN (
    SELECT media_id FROM keylinks WHERE keyword_id = '6'
) AND media_id IN (
    SELECT media_id FROM keylinks WHERE keyword_id = '8'
)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for... Seems a bit resource intensive though. Is there a lighter methodology for this?

Comment: When you say "seem a bit resource intensive", do you say that because of gut feeling or profiling?

Comment: I mean its going to add TWO select queries per result. If I am getting 50 results... thats 100 extra queries per page.

Comment: Those two subselects are run *only once* for the entire query, not for each result (unless I misunderstand you). The only thing that would make we worry about this query is if you had many, many keyword_ids in one query.